# Using Android asynchronous Palette generator for color transition animation

Tags: android, asynchronous, transition, palette

In my app I have a ViewPager that holds images. When the user scrolls through the images, there is a color animation that transitions the action bar color and status bar color between the two bitmap's palette's vibrant colors. The issue I see is that while it works great, it becomes very choppy when large images are selected.

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    Palette paletteBefore = Palette.from(imagePagerAdapter.bitmap.get(position)).generate();
    Palette paletteAfter = Palette.from(imagePagerAdapter.bitmap.get(position + 1)).generate();

    //Using this to get the average color between the two palette colors at the current position offset.
    int color = (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(positionOffset, paletteBefore.getVibrantColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3")), paletteAfter.getVibrantColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3")));
    int darkColor = (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(positionOffset, paletteBefore.getDarkVibrantColor(Color.parseColor("#1976D2")), paletteAfter.getDarkVibrantColor(Color.parseColor("#1976D2")));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(darkColor);
    }
}
```

I know that there is a built-in asynchronous method that generates the palette in a background thread, but I am unable to access the generated palette:

```
Palette.from(imagePagerAdapter.bitmap.get(position)).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
        paletteBefore = p; //Variable "paletteBefore" is accessed from within class, needs to be declared final 
    }
 });
```

Even if I create a global variable to hold a palette object, it always ends up being null. I have no idea how to solve this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is generating them asynchronously.

You cannot guarantee that both palettes will be created at the same time just in time to generate your colors.

The time taken will depend on the size of the image.

I would move all palette generation out of onPageScrolled()

Try creating the palettes as soon as the bitmap is accessible from each of your fragment/view

That way there might be a better chance of having them by the time the user scrolls.